# How do .push() and .reduce() work together here? (fibonacci)

Tags: javascript, push, reduce

I've done an assignment, where a function's output is the last number of a fibonacci-array. Truth it, I got stuck hard on this one and I found the code in the second else if statement on stackoverflow. But I can't wrap my head around it, how this is working exactly.

**Here is the code:**

```js
const fibonacci = function(input) {
    let n = Number(input);
        if (n === 1) {
            return 1;
        } else if (n < 1) {
            return "OOPS";
        } else if (n > 1) {
            let array = new Array(n);                              // <---- Starting here
            let filled = array.fill(1);
            let reduced = filled.reduce((acc, _, i) => {
                acc.push((i <=1) ? i : acc[i-2] + acc[i-1])
                    return acc;                          
            },[]);
return reduced[n - 1] + reduced[n - 2];
        }
}
```

**My question:** Why does `reduced` returns an Array instead of a single value? And since it returns an array - why won't the `push`'ed numbers get added to the initial array, which already has values in it? -> let's say `input = 4` then `filled = [1, 1, 1, 1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const fibonacci = function(input) {
    let n = Number(input);
        if (n === 1) {
            return 1;
        } else if (n < 1) {
            return "OOPS";
        } else if (n > 1) {
            let array = new Array(n);                              // <---- Starting here
            let filled = array.fill(1);
            let reduced = filled.reduce((acc, _, i) => {
                acc.push((i <=1) ? i : acc[i-2] + acc[i-1])
                    return acc;                          
            },[]); // <- reduce is initialized with an array (new array),
return reduced[n - 1] + reduced[n - 2];
        }
}
```

as reduce is initialized with a new array, the function is reducing (adding new values to the new initialized array) and returning the same.

here how the reducers work
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce